# Unix redirection issue: </dev/null 1>&- 2>&- &

Tags: shell, unix

Unix redirection:

Recently I faced an issue where one of the script was using the command below to execute it in background. The issue was that the script was executing twice when it is started.

For example:

In the script I put an echo "Hello" to print to log file. When the script executed I saw in the log file that it printed twice at the same time. Can any one tell me what caused here to execute the script twice.

```
nohup <runScript> </dev/null 1>&- 2>&- &
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. Please indent code by selecting it and either using the **`{}`** button above the edit box or typing control-K. Also, look at the question you post to ensure that it says what you expect it to say. Because the code was being treated as text, the `<runScript>` vanished as it is not valid HTML markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original version of your question was slightly confusing. The subject line asks about (with command and argument inferred):

```
somecmd arg1 </dev/null 1>&- 2>&- &
```

The body of the question appeared to ask about:

```
nohup &- 2>&- &
```

which could reasonably be inferred to mean:

```
nohup somecmd arg1 &- 2>&- &
```

The edited version of your question is also confusing — though the change was just to indent code fragment.  The notation `<runscript>` is ill-chosen when you are asking about I/O redirections. I'm guessing that what you wrote as `<runscript>` is equivalent to me writing `somecmd`, rather than redirecting standard input from `runscript` and an ill-formed output redirection. However, the revised
code does at least match the subject line:

```
nohup runScript </dev/null 1>&- 2>&- &
```

So, I'll ignore the `&-` notation (a previous version of this answer did not).

#### Notation `</dev/null 1>&- 2>&- &`

The first command line redirects standard input from `/dev/null`, and closes both standard output and standard error and executes the command in background.  Redirecting from `/dev/null` is good; closing standard output and standard error is not so good — programs are entitled to have those three file descriptors open, and that can be done by redirecting to `/dev/null` too:

```
somecmd arg1 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or:

```
somecmd arg1 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
```

There is not much difference between these two.

#### Double running

There is nothing in any of the code that would account for the script being run twice, or the output appearing in a log file twice. Since you have not shown the script that was run, we cannot deduce any cause from that. On the whole, the charge would be 'operator error' — you managed to run the command twice.  If you want us to look into that, you'll have to provide a reproducible script that:

- Shows the script to be run.
- Empties the log file.
- Runs the script once with your chosen notation.
- Shows that the log file contains two entries.

Without such a reproducible script, there's nothing anyone can do to help you.

Comment: Thanks Much for your reply. I will definitely try to improve the way i asking questions. What you mean by closing both standard output and standard error, are you mean to say,standard output and standard error wont be printed any where ?

Comment: Closing the standard I/O channels means that the file descriptors (0 for input, 1 for output, 2 for error) are not open; any attempt by the program to read from standard input will get an EBADF (bad file descriptor) error, and any attempt to write to standard output or standard error will get the same error. By contrast, if you reconnect to `/dev/null`, the file descriptors are open, but there is no data available to read (so the program gets an EOF non-error indication) and any data written is thrown away (successfully). The C standard requires that programs have open standard I/O channels.